# Is it possible to execute a smart-contract function at the next (or other block) number?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

I simply need a function to be executed not at the block number when the function is initiated but to wait for any of the next block numbers.

I can do this with a require, where person executes the function twice. First time it records the current block number, second time it confirms that it is the next block number. However, this is confusing, annoying, and takes extra gas money.

What I want to accomplish is a pause, which (unless I am wrong) does not exist with solidity.

However, if pause does exist, I do not need seconds, just the block number instead.

Comment: No, the only way to do it is by recording the current block number in a state variable, as you've described (though, `require` cannot be useful here in any way, because if you revert the transaction, then the block number will not be recorded in the state variable).

Comment: Cool, thanks!  Briefly, first you record the block number, override (lets say a 0) and break. Second call, you require if not 0. But yes, it does get more complicated than this but it is possible to do it.

Comment: Well, you can simply use a single state variable indicating the block number. If it's currently 0, then you set it to the block number and return. If it's larger than 0, then you perform the actual functionality that you want, and then set it back to 0 (which will give you back some of the "extra" gas spent on the previous step). So again - `require` does not seem to be useful here.

Comment: BTW, block number and timestamp (seconds) are synonymous in your use-case, since every block has a single number and a single timestamp (different for every block).

Comment: Yes, the way I explained it... a single-state variable would be a better option. Bigger picture, however is different and I wish I could explain it all here. I could post a link when it is done.